# Docker for Windows Beta release notes and version history

Tags: docker

Where can I find the release history and release notes for Docker for Windows beta channel? One of my users has recently picked up an error and I have no idea if her build is the latest version and thus if this bug was introduced into the beta recently and then Windows recently silently updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check if those release notes are for that beta:

[docker-for-windows/release-notes/#/beta-release-notes](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/release-notes/#/beta-release-notes)

The latest ones are Beta 26 Release Notes (2016-09-14 1.12.1-beta26)